Why is ISAAC discouraged in 2024?
I have made and shared a password manager project in a forum, which implements ISAAC cipher. Many  users pointed out that ISAAC has found weak states and thus should be refrain from, but I think that doesn't change its identity as CSPRNG, thus I want to listen your opinions on whether this controversial cipher should be discourage forever?

If you're using a password manager then I presume that you are usin ISAAC to encrypt passwords. I would strongly advice you not to do so.

First of all, the ISAAC cipher seems to have been constructed on the wrong premise:

"I developed (...) tests to break a generator, and I developed the generator to pass the tests. The generator is ISAAC."[3]

Creating tests for a generic generator does not cover all possible crypt-analysis, so to me this puts the entire premise of the cipher in doubt.

Secondly, the ISAAC cipher isn't used, maintained or analyzed much. It states on the official website that RC4 has not been broken. That's a statement that I would definitely contest.

Thirdly, the weak states are an indication that other vulnerabilities may exist. In themselves they will probably not allow an adversary to break your scheme, but it is a clear indication that the original author did not anticipate that kind or level of analysis.

But most importantly, better stream ciphers and CSPRNG's exist. There is no reason to choose an old algorithm that doesn't seem to have been devised with the best crypt-analysis in mind.
The main advantages of ISAAC seem to be simplicity and speed, but a well designed cryptographic library should take care of those problems anyway.
